# Replace Stream API operation with JPQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a service with following method:

```
public Collection<List<GaUtm>> getGaUtmGroupedByAccountLogin(List<String> loginsOfArchivedGaAccounts) {
   return gaUtmRepository.findAll()
           .stream()
           .filter(gaUtm -> !loginsOfArchivedGaAccounts.contains(gaUtm.getGaUtmId().getAccountLogin()))
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(gaUtm -> gaUtm.getGaUtmId().getAccountLogin())).values(); 

    }
```

I want to replace it with Spring Data + JPQL:

```
@Repository
public interface GaUtmRepository extends JpaRepository<GaUtm, GaUtmId> {

 @Query(...)
 Collection<List<GaUtm>> findGaUtmGroupedByAccountLogin(List<String> loginsOfArchivedGaAccounts);

}
```

I'm stuck with grouping by and what should i select:

```
SELECT ... FROM GaUtm utm.. WHERE utm.gaUtmId.accountLogin NOT IN :loginsOfArchivedGaAccounts
```

Entity:

```
public class GaUtm {

    @EmbeddedId
    private GaUtmId csGaUtmId;

}

@Embeddable
public class GaUtmId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "account_login")
    private String accountLogin;
}
```

Comment: As `Etienne Miret` mentioned, you cannot use SQL/JPA QL to produce directly the result you need. At least not without executing separated query for each group. I do not think that's the way to go. Closest thing is to do `WHERE` filtering away the undesired data and `ORDER BY` the grouping attribute and then iterating over the result and starting new group as soon the grouping attribute changes. On practical note, it might be okay enough simply do only the `WHERE` clause and keeping the `collect` on the stream (and getting rid of the `filter` on the stream).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use SQL grouping for what you want to achieve.

`Collectors.groupingBy ()` partitions your dataset into groups, producing a list of values for each key, whereas the SQL `GROUP BY` operator do aggregation (sum, average, count...), producing a single row for each key.

You can increase your service performance by asking the DB to do the filtering, but the grouping operation must be done in the service.